# Replacing jcenter() in Android Gradle Repositories

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

Per [JFrog](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/), they are sunsetting Bintray (which includes JCenter) on May 1st, 2021.

To prep for this, I opened my `build.gradle` and replaced `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()`. My `build.gradle` now looks like this (with some parts removed):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        // jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        // ...
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        // jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

However, since replacing `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()`, I receive this error:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Redacted'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.2

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Is there another repository I can add to resolve this, or does `com.android.tools:sdk-common` need to update to use a different version of `org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j`?

**Update:** Version 4.1.3 still has the same issue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

JetBrains [copied](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-261387#focus=Comments-27-4820597.0-0) `org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824` to Maven Central, which resolves this error.

If you use additional dependencies that have not yet migrated to Maven Central, you should reach out directly to them.

---

**Update:** "We listened to the community and will keep JCenter as a read-only repository **indefinitely**. Our customers and the community can continue to rely on JCenter as a reliable mirror for Java packages." [source](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/)

**Update:** Google is working on a fix for build tools 4.2 and maybe 4.1 as well. [source](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109894262#comment7)

**Update:** You could try a [dependency resolve rule](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109894262#comment11).

---

The top-level dependency, `com.android.tools.build:gradle`, started using a newer version of `trove4j` in `7.0.0-alpha01`. ([`7.0.0-alpha12` is currently the latest.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google))

Dependency chain:
`com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha01 -> com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.0-alpha01 -> com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.3.0-alpha01 -> org.jetbrains.intellij.deps:trove4j:1.0.20181211`

However, this version is still in alpha and requires Android Studio 4.3+, which isn't even in Beta yet.

I have filed a bug with Google here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179291081

Comment: Thanks for the updates and links but what can we do right now to fix this? resolutionStrategies in the google link don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is outdated and is not useful anymore atleast as jcenter is down again with error of 403.
The most useful answer can be found here [Finally after hours of head bangs, issue resolved.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74261483/6818426)

Update `android/build.gradle`, add the following at the top in `allprojects -> repositories`.

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
          println repo.url.toString()
          if (repo.url.toString().startsWith("https://jcenter.bintray.com/")) {
              project.logger.warn "Repository ${repo.url} removed."
              remove repo
              mavenCentral()
          }
      }
      gradlePluginPortal() // add this if you get further errors 
      ...other repos
  }
}
```

Thanks.