# Is JCenter down permanently (31 Oct)?

Tags: android, maven, jcenter

> **Moderator Note**: This appears to be a service outage. Stack Overflow [cannot provide support for this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

```
   > Failed to list versions for com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-android/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-android/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Read timed out
```

I was trying to build an Android app, but I got the above error. When I connect to “https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-android/maven-metadata.xml”, an nginx 403 error appears. Is JCenter down? What should I do?

Comment: jcentre is down. There are many sites where you can check the status. One of them is https://statusgator.com/services/bintray. All you can do is wait for it to be up and running again.

Comment: Though the deprecation of jcenter update came by Feb,2021. today there was an temp incident report in Gradle. Because of this, the issue had happened to the users. I have attached the incident link and jcenter deprecation link here. Click [JCenter shutdown impact on Gradle builds](https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown "JCenter shutdown impact on Gradle builds") Click [JCenter issues,Incident Report for Gradle](https://status.gradle.com/incidents/c65zmfw32lpm "JCenter issues")

Comment: Voting to reopen. The title is possibly misleading; JCenter is down, but this is expected to be _permanent_. Because of this, users will still need workarounds and a healthy discussion on the best solutions will be valuable to the community. Perhaps renaming this question to: "JCentre may be down permanently. What are our options?" or similar so it's clear it's not just a temporary downtime.

Comment: If you need to build quickly whilst sorting out JCenter, you can always build in Gradle offline mode.  `gradle --offline build`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

### Update: Nov 8, 2022

There is yet another incident. Follow [the incident here](https://status.gradle.com/incidents/9j9bx7nlwwf1)

---

### tldr;

Yes. JCenter is down right now. But there is a way to fix the issue. JCenter was sunset a while ago and remained available in read-only mode. So far there isn't any update on when it will be available again. Depending your situation, you have quick or **not so-quick** options for you.

---

### **Where can I check status?**

New incident is reported here. [Check this out](https://status.gradle.com/incidents/9740r6bzx438).

As @Adrian mentioned in a comment, you can check the status of the current incident on [Gradle's incident status page](https://status.gradle.com/incidents/c65zmfw32lpm). The status shows "Resolved", but I still can’t make the project. So I wonder if that status page just shows the impact of JCenter on Gradle Plugin Portal and not the status of JCenter in general.

---

### **What can I do now?**

### Recommended Update:

Now that incident is resolved by updating gradlePluginPortal to serve as JCenter mirror (almost), it's highly possible that adding following repositories before `jcenter()` should resolve the issue:

```
google()
mavenCentral()
gradlePluginPortal()
```

### Temporary solution:

Toggle offline mode of Gradle as shown below. This will work for the local machine, but it won’t work for [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) though.

[image: Toggle offline mode option]

### Robust solution:

It's always a good idea to move away from a deprecated service. **Most** active libraries are now hosted on other popular repositories like the Google repository, [Maven Central](https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DEV/pages/1123844333/Use+of+Maven+Central) or the Gradle plugin repository.

To add those repositories in your project, add following in repositories block (you might already have those). Order matters. Make sure to put them before `jcenter()` this tells Gradle to look into other repositories before trying to pull from `jcenter()`.

Tip: Do a global search for `jcenter()` and ensure every repository block that contains `jcenter()` has these other repositories.

```
 repositories {
    ...
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal() 
    jcenter()
    ...
 }
```

Do Gradle sync and clean build and see if that works.

---

### **Didn't that work?**

Don't worry (yet). This is common. The above solution won’t work alone for some situations:

1. When moved from `jcenter()` to other repository (like `mavenCentral()`), authors decided to update the version number. This simply means you need to update the version of that dependency to fetch it from other repository. Look for the library that shows up as unavailable in failed build log. Find its GitHub or development documentation to check the latest version. Gradle Sync + clean build.
2. The repositories that we just added are popular ones, but they are not the only ones. When authors of library had to switch from JCenter to somewhere else, they did not choose one of these. In such cases, check the GitHub page or developers documentation. Usually authors put the required repository on those pages. If you find that repository is not present in your project, add it. Gradle Sync + clean build.

   - **Beware**: Some authors chose repository options like `jitpack.io` largely because it was quick and easier than others. But you should be aware of concerns with that. [Melix](https://github.com/melix) from Gradle [summarizes the concerns](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/16310#issuecomment-785945980)  with jitpack.io. Because of potential security issues, I recommend to consult team and security expert before adding that.
3. Well, now it's time for little worry. It's highly possible that you are using some library that is deprecated or no longer maintained. Find GitHub page of the library and see if author declared it deprecated or no-longer maintained in readme. You can even check when it got last commit. If it was a while ago, it means it's no longer maintained and author did not care to move library from `jcenter()` to any other repo.

   - Go to GitHub issues of the repository. Someone must have posted question regarding plan to move from `jcenter`. If you are in luck, someone might even have created fork and hosted that fork somewhere else. For example, I use `spanny` in one of the projects and author did not move it. [GustavoRoss  cared](https://github.com/binaryfork/Spanny/issues/9#issuecomment-840865168) enough to fork and move.
   - No one forked and moved? Then you have two options.

     1. Look for an alternate active library that does the same for you. Of course this is time consuming, but again a good idea to move away from deprecated resource.
     2. If you don't have time to integrate new library or no other library exist, then be the hero and make fork of GitHub project and move.
4. But hey, I don't remember putting library in question in my code base? This means, it's a transitive dependency (a dependency of your direct dependency). Again check, latest version of your direct dependency and hopefully new version has fixed this.

**How can I check a direct and transitive dependency?**

- your failed build log has the answer.

[image: Build log annotated screenshot]

Hopefully by this point you got the build working. If not, then hope for JCenter to come back soon and start planning to move away from it.

Comment: [Gradle's status page](https://status.gradle.com/) also shows outages related to JCenter. Recently [here](https://status.gradle.com/incidents/c65zmfw32lpm)

Comment: here is a grep you can run in your project that will output all the occurences of jcenter in your repository, you can use this as a starting point to investigate what libraries you might need to update: `grep -rnw "jcenter" * > output-file.
txt`

Comment: Run this command to see what dependencies you have that are reliant on jCenter and then remove or upgrade the dependencies:

```shell
for FILE in `find . |grep build.gradle`; do echo $FILE; cat $FILE |grep jcenter; done
```

[Source: github related issue](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/issues/248#issuecomment-1297204559)

Answer (score 29):

Finally after hours of head bangs, the issue was resolved. In `android/build.gradle`, add the following at the top in `allprojects` -> `repositories`.

It will remove `jcenter()` from all the dependencies during the configuration phase and replace it with `mavenCentral()`.

It should look something like this:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
          println repo.url.toString()
          if (repo.url.toString().startsWith("https://jcenter.bintray.com/")) {
              project.logger.warn "Repository ${repo.url} removed."
              remove repo
              mavenCentral()
          }
      }
      gradlePluginPortal() // Add this if you get further errors
      ...other repositories
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you are not alone.
JCenter seems down today.

My solution is change all the `jCenter` to `mavenCentral`
from `root/android/build.gradle`.

Also, don't forget the libraries `node_module/*error library*/android/build.gradle`.

Comment: mavenCentral is not the complete alternative to jcenter. I would suggest to keep both

Comment: @Mahesh Thank you for the infomation. I will keep them both now

Comment: With the many misspellings, this answer is unlikely to be correct.

Answer (score 6):

I just meet this problem as well, and I'm not quite sure why JCenter returns 403, but you can fix this problem by adding `mavenCentral()` before `jcenter()` in repositories setting, like this:

```
    repositories {
        ...
        mavenCentral() // Add this line
        jcenter()
        ...
    }
```

Comment: This will work for most dependencies but if you are using some dependency that is not uploaded to mavenCentral or even a transitive dependency that is not uploaded to mavenCentral then you (and I) are at mercy of jcenter. We can wait and hope for jcenter to fix or add a new tech debt urgent task to move away from that dependency (or hopefully version). Easier said than done.

Answer (score 6):

I think Maven Central is not the complete alternative to JCenter.
I'm using aliyun's mirror. Replace `jcenter()` with `maven { url "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter" }`.

I don't know if it’s accessible from outside of China, or does aliyun censorship some packages, or if it is it up-to-date.

Guide to replace:

In file *android/build.gradle*:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    repositories {
        ...
-        jcenter()
+       maven { url "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter" }
    }
}
allprojects {
+   buildscript {
+       repositories {
+           maven { url "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter" }
+       }
+   }
    repositories {
        ...
-       jcenter()
+       maven { url "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter" }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did the work for me. What are the "things to know" and what could be the consequences of using this?

Comment: Worked for me, from Egypt, thanks