# app:lintVitalRelease Causing app build to failed React Native

Tags: android, react-native, gradlew

On trying to build apk, I am getting the below error

Task :app:lintVitalRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-community_checkbox:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
Required by:
project :react-native-community_checkbox

> Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
> Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
> Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
> Read timed out

Versions Used:
"@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.9",
"react-native": "0.66.1",

Comment: jcenter is down

Comment: Is it temporary or permanent?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like it is permanent, you can look here for solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74258160/is-jcenter-down-permanently-31-oct