# How to solve 'Failed to resolve' error in Android?

Tags: android

Failed to resolve: `com.github.warkiz.widget:indicatorseekbar:2.1.2`
Show in Project Structure dialog
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Failed to resolve: `hari.bounceview:bounceview:0.1.0`
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

[image]

Comment: Could it be that this is something that hasn't been built for a few years, and you're encountering this https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown ? Can you otherwise confirm these exist in any of your `repositories`? They don't appear to exist on maven central, although a similarly named project exists here https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/io.github.hariprasanths/bounceview-android/0.2.0

Comment: I don't understand, I am working on the source code of reskin apps...

Comment: The error just indicates that it cannot locate that version, of that artifact, for that group id. Without knowing which `repositories` you are pulling built jars from, it's hard to provide a clearer reason why those packages specifically can't be found, i.e. if an older version of the same package exists, or if the package is no longer hosted. All it indicates is that they can't be found. You'll need to have a look at which `repositories` your project is requesting the packages from. It looks like both packages still exist on github though, which somewhat different names.

Answer (score 0):

JCenter is [no longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74258160/is-jcenter-down-permanently-31-oct) available

One possible solution [could be](https://github.com/warkiz/IndicatorSeekBar/issues/226) to use previous version 2.1.1

```
com.github.warkiz:IndicatorSeekBar:v2.1.1
```

If that doesn't work, either find the package or build it yourself then and manually add it to you project or add the library code itself in your project.